# How to correct for multiple testing with enrichment test?

Tags: p-value

I run enrichment test to find genes mutated at a different rate within one clusters of samples compared outside it based on a two-tailed Fisher’s exact test.

So finally I have a matrix **5x10** of **pvalues**.

I wonder how to correct them for multiple testing. Should I correct by genes or by clusters ?

Answer (score 0):

if you have SNP data such that all your clusters have more or less the same p-values then it is my understanding that you should pick a random p-value from each cluster and then use these when you are correcting from multiple testing, and subsequently correct the entire cluster with that p-values correction value, if there is large differences within the cluster I think you should correct by gene.

Comment: Many thank for your answer. In fact pvalues are really different within the cluster so I should correct by gene. Could you share your intuition behind that ?

Comment: my base intuituion: 1) if you have 50 tests and you use all 50 tests you should correct for 50 tests, 2) if you are only interested in the groups you should agregate everything within the group into 1 test (ie average the p-values, anova  or something smarter). If you want to say gene a and b in the same cluster are both significant then obviously you have to correct for both a and b, ie if you have the potential for 50 positive test then you should obviously correct for 50 test...